# Should I return Task<IEnumerable<T>> or IAsyncEnumerable<T> from repository?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

What is the correct way of repository implementation in EF Core?

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<Order> GetOrder(int orderId)
{
    return blablabla.AsAsyncEnumerable();
}
```

or

```
public Task<IEnumerable<Order>> GetOrder(int orderId)
{
    return blablabla.ToListAsync();
}
```

Is it performance wise to call `AsAsyncEnumerable()`? Is this approach safe?
From one hand it doesn't create `List<T>` object so it should be slightly faster. But from the order hand the query is not materialized so we deffer the SQL execution and the result can change in the meantime.

Comment: See https://medium.com/@ben.k.muller/c-ienumerable-vs-list-and-array-9f099f157f4f

Comment: this article isn't answering any of my questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The decision really comes down to whether you wish to buffer or stream.

If you want to **buffer** the results, use `ToList()` or `ToListAsync()`.
If you want to **stream** the results, use `AsEnumerable()` or `AsAsyncEnumerable()`.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-querying#buffering-and-streaming):

> Buffering refers to loading all your query results into memory, whereas streaming means that EF hands the application a single result each time, never containing the entire resultset in memory. In principle, the memory requirements of a streaming query are fixed - they are the same whether the query returns 1 row or 1000; a buffering query, on the other hand, requires more memory the more rows are returned. For queries that result large resultsets, this can be an important performance factor.

In general, it's best to stream, unless you *need* to buffer.

When you stream, once the data is read, you can't read it again without hitting the DB again. So if you need to read the same data more than once, you'll need to buffer.

If a repository streams a `IEnumerable`, the caller could choose to buffer it by calling `ToList()` (or `ToListAsync()` on `IAsyncEnumerable`). We lose this flexibility if the repository chooses to return an IList.

So to answer your question, you're better off to the repository stream the result. And let the caller decide if they want to buffer.

---

If the team working on the project is not comfortable with stream semantics, or if most of the code already buffers, it might make sense to suffix the methods that stream with something like `AsStream` (eg. `GetOrdersAsStream()`) so that they know they shouldn't be enumerating it more than once.

So a repository could have:

```
async Task<List<Order>> GetOrders() => await GetOrdersAsStream.ToListAsync();
IAsyncEnumerable<Order> GetOrdersAsStream() => ...
```

Comment: AsEnumerable () defers the execution until it starts to enumerate the result. So the method in the first example (with IAsyncEnumerable return type) doesn't materialize query inside repository

Comment: @JanKowalski I see. I've updated the answer. It doesn't matter whether it hits DB within the repository or not, when we're aware about whether the data is being streamed (and thereby going to cause a DB hit on each enumeration) or if it's buffered.

Answer (score 7):

According to [source](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/8144d50ec0d15b87c35a9a3a425b1faadafb87f1/src/EFCore/Extensions/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs#L2384) `.ToListAsync` will use `IAsyncEnumerable` internally anyway, so there's not much of performance benefits in one or another.
But one important feature of `.ToListAsync` or `.ToArrayAsync` is [cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/cancel-async-tasks-after-a-period-of-time).

```cs
public static async Task<List<TSource>> ToListAsync<TSource>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var list = new List<TSource>();
    await foreach (var element in source.AsAsyncEnumerable().WithCancellation(cancellationToken))
    {
        list.Add(element);
    }
    return list;
}
```

List will basically hold everything in memory but it might be a serious performance concern only if the list is really big. In this case you might consider paging your big response.

```cs
public Task<List<Order>> GetOrders(int orderId, int offset, int limit)
{
    return blablabla.Skip(offset).Take(limit).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Isn't there any performance benefit if the item you are looking for is the first item for example?  asyncEnumerableList.firstOrDefaultAsync() over list.firstOrDefault()?